# Incomplete Items in Search Scope and Result

Tags: 2007, search, search-results, search-scope, scope

On the Search Scope of our site, referencing to the /Pages path and performed a full crawl. However after the crawl I only got 2 items but on my pages folder I have 4309 Items.

I know that the Items on the Search Scope is just an estimate so to test the results I tried to search .aspx and I got only 2 results.

I already checked the Crawl rules but there were no rules conflicting on what I wanted. I've also checked the Site Settings > Pages > Advanced Settings > Search >  Allow items from this document library to appear in search results 
is set to YES.

Would you know other way for me to check what is wrong with our Search.

Comment: Are the pages checked in? The crawl does not index drafts

Comment: Yes they are all checked in.

Comment: What is the Scope Rule?

Comment: Scope Rule Type: Web Address
Web Address: http://webname:8801/dv/advisories/Pages
Behavior: Include

Comment: Please note there is a http:// for the Web address :)

Comment: Hi, after several full crawl my items is now 1024 which is still not equal to 4309 items of my pages folder.